# Should I ignore .copyarea.db file when commiting a new file to RTC source control?

Tags: clearcase, rtc

I'm transferring a clearcase source controlled project into RTC source control.

I think I should not commit the below file

```
.copyarea.db
```

Since this is a clearcase specific file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore it: It is for CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client) Web views only, and would be useless in a Jazz view.

More precisely, from the IBM technote "[About the `.copyarea.dat` and `.copyarea.db` files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21119280)":

> Each CCRC or CCWeb view root directory (the directory tree where the files from the VOB are downloaded into the local view workspace) contains a `.copyarea.dat` and a `.copyarea.db` file.
>
> - **`.COPYAREA.DAT`**:
>     The `.copyarea.dat` file is **used to detect if changes have been made to the loaded files to determine if they are in a hijacked state**.
>     The .copyarea.dat file stores information like:
>
>   - When a view was created
>   - What http server the view was originally connecting to
>   - The view's Operating System platform
>   - CCRC remote view tag
> - **`.COPYAREA.DB`**:
>     The `.copyarea.db` file is created in each directory of a CCRC or CCWeb view which contains a **list of files that are loaded in the view as well as metadata about the files**.
>     If this file is missing or corrupt, you will notice that all or some of the loaded files will appear to be hijacked.

Again, you don't need those information with an RTC jazz view.