# Using both Git and Clearcase: How can we check in Git code changes to a new Clearcase version?

Tags: git, version-control, clearcase

Our project currently uses **ClearCase** for source control. This limits our development, so we are going to move to **Git**. Unfortunately, for contract reasons, we have to continue to maintain our code in ClearCase. **We are going to be using Git for day-to-day development, but we will have to check in our code to Clearcase each release**. What is the best way to do this?

*Example*

Let's say the Git code is v7.0, while in Clearcase it is still v6.0. Given the Git v7.0 codebase, I'd like ClearCase to somehow be able to figure out automagically what files have changed since v6.0. Is there a way to easily insert all the Git code changes from v6.0 to v7.0 into ClearCase as one big v7.0 commit within ClearCase?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use the ClearCase command **[`clearfsimport`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17070750/6309)**: it will import any folder (Like the root folder of a git working tree) into your ClearCase (snapshot or dynamic) view.

It will detect the modified, removed or added files.

Once the import is done, you can put a label on all the current versions, or if you are using UCM  a baseline.

Remember that ClearCase works file by file and has no notion of a repository wide commit or revision. Hence the label or baseline after the import.

See more about the differences between ClearCase and Git in "[What are the basic clearcase concepts every developer should know?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309)".

> Does it matter if the Git code does not have the appropriate .copyarea.db files when we run the clearfsimport command?

See "[Should I ignore `.copyarea.db` file when committing a new file to RTC source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12785521/6309)"

---

It doesn't matter, as long as the `clearfsimport` doesn't attempt to import it (you could remove it from the git working tree).
See also "[Clearfsimport imports `.copyarea.db` files as file elements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM80966)"

However, it also means CCRC web view, which means [`clearfsimport` is probably not available](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21358355) on the client post: you might want to do that import from a dedicated post with a full ClearCase client installed (instead of just CCRC).

Comment: Thanks! Does it matter if the Git code does not have the appropriate .copyarea.db files when we run the clearfsimport command?

Comment: @user891242 I have edited my answer to address your point (as well as illustrating the `clearfsimport` command with some related links)

Comment: Thanks! We use CCRC to connect to a ClearCase server managed by the government, but I believe we should be able to access that server.

The clearfsimport command is run from the ClearCase server, right? (not the CCRC)

Comment: @user891242 yes, the clearfsimport would have to be run from the server (which has the full ClearCase installed, as well as the CCRC server).

Comment: Thanks! I will mark this as answered when it comes time to check in our code. You've been a great help!